# Lifecycle/Scope of @WebServlet

Tags: servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)

I have a weird (but probably expected) behaviour in my WebServlet. Environment is:
- Apache 2.2.x
- Glassfish 3.1.1 + mod_jk
- JSF Mojarra 2.1.3

I have an abstract servlet that implements some code to check in the FacesContext/Session if there is a specific @SessionScoped managed bean and if so, whether the user is signed-in. If user is signed-in, then proceeds to the file delivery. The implementing @WebServlet only provides the actual file download.

Abstract Servlet:

```
public abstract class SecureDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
private UserProductBean userProductBean;
private UserInfoView userInfoView = null;

private UserInfoView getUserInfoView(HttpServletRequest req) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context != null) {
        userInfoView = (UserInfoView) context.getApplication()
                .getELResolver().getValue(FacesContext.
                getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), null, "userInfoView");
    }
    if (userInfoView == null) {
        userInfoView = (UserInfoView) getServletContext().
                getAttribute("userInfoView");
    }
    if (userInfoView == null) {
        userInfoView = (UserInfoView) req.getSession().
                getAttribute("userInfoView");
    }
    return userInfoView;
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (getUserInfoView(req) == null || !getUserInfoView(req).getLoggedIn()) {
        response.sendRedirect("message.xhtml?msg=noLogin");
        return;
    }
    doDownload(req, response);
}


public abstract void doDownload(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException;

}
```

Then I have a @WebServlet that extends the above abstract HttpServlet and implements the abstract method:

```
@WebServlet(name = "SecureImageServlet", urlPatterns = {"/print","/m/print"})
public class SecureImageServlet extends SecureDownloadServlet {

  @Override
  public void doDownload(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws IOException, ServletException {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Now here is the issue:
- From computer A, sign in, then call the SecureImageServlet servlet to get a file (i.e. http://www.example.com/print?id=12345). The `userInfoView` session bean is initialized as expected, and the file is delivered.
- From computer B, without being signed-in, call http://www.example.com/print?id=12345. The `userInfoView` is already initialized with the session of user on computer A!!! And the file is delivered too.

It looks like the WebServlet becomes ApplicationScope or something like that. Is it the @EJB injection that does that?
Note the the instance of `userInfoView` is the same (the object id in the debugger shows the same number) which means somehow the computer B is seen as the same user as computer A

Edited format

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909

Comment: By the way, I've removed the JSF tag as this has completely nothing to do with JSF. Servlet is an entirely distinct API. Attempting to get the `FacesContext` in a Servlet class makes also no utter sense. Just remove those lines.

Comment: Thanks and yes, I noticed the FacesContext stuff was always null and that trying to get it was not a smart move. I've cleaned it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a friend of mine (without an account on SO :) ) pointed out my mistake:
I am using `userInfoView` as a class member instead of keeping it within the request scope. I fixed it by removing the class member and voila!

Comment: yep, read the lifecycle of a servlet on the SO sevlet page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info A servlet is created once and all requests flow through that instance.

Comment: A shame I did such a code. I knew that but just been working with JSF View/Request scopes and Jersey RESTful Web Services for so long I overlooked that Servlet are not JSF :)